# Why it's not removing the right doors from the list?

Tags: unity, c#

```
GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorLeft);
        GameObject[] doorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorRight);

        List<GameObject> allDoors = doorsLeft.Union(doorsRight).ToList();

        for(int i = 0; i < allDoors.Count; i++)
        {
            if(allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != "Wall_Door_Long_01" && allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != "Wall_Door_Long_02")
            {
                allDoors.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        foreach(GameObject door in allDoors)
        {
            Debug.Log("Door Parent : " + door.transform.parent);
        }
```

If it's not "Wall_Door_Long_01" and not "Wall_Door_Long_01" then remove the item from the list.

After that when I'm doing a loop on the allDoors again and debug log the parents I see that some of the parents are not "Wall_Door_Long_01" and not "Wall_Door_Long_02" but after removing they all should be only "Wall_Door_Long_01" or "Wall_Door_Long_02"

Maybe the comparison is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you remove at index N, the next value in the list will take it place, and it will be skipped in verification, because you increment an index.

**Solution 1.** Firstly create a list of items to be removed, and then use it as source for removal.

```
    List<GameObject> allDoors = doorsLeft.Union(doorsRight).ToList();
    List<GameObject> toRemove = new List<GameObject>();
        for(int i = 0; i < allDoors.Count; i++)
        {
            if(allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != "Wall_Door_Long_01" && allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != "Wall_Door_Long_02")
            {
                toRemove.Add(allDoors[i]);
            }
        }
        foreach(var it in toRemove)
        {
             allDoors.Remove(it);
        }
```

**Solution 2.** Right after removing at index N, decrement index variable to check the new element at this index again next loop iteration.

```
allDoors.RemoveAt(i);
i--;
```

Comment: You could iterate the list as well backwards with for(int i = allDoors.Count - 1; i >=0 ; i--)